# Read and Write commands into a single CMD process

Tags: c#, cmd

Hi I want to start a single cmd process from which i can read and write from my windows application form. I want to highlight that i dont want to keep on create a new cmd process for each command that i enter. My code is a mess now. . .
I have a windows form application now with just 2 textboxes and a button.
Textbox1 is for the output.
Textbox2 in for the input.
Button is to send the input.

```
    Process cmd = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
         FileName = "cmd.exe",

         UseShellExecute = false,
         CreateNoWindow = true,
         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
         RedirectStandardInput = true
    };

    StreamReader sr;
    StreamWriter sw;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.StartInfo = psi;
        cmd.Start();

        sr = cmd.StandardOutput;

        sw = cmd.StandardInput;
        sw.AutoFlush = true;

        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(GetOutput));
        t.Start();

    }

    delegate void Write(string Text);
    private void SetTextBox(string Text)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke(new Write(SetTextBox),Text);
        }
        else
            textBox1.Text += Text;
    }

    private void GetOutput()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (sr.Peek() != -1)
                SetTextBox(sr.ReadToEnd());
            else
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        textBox2.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: After i enter a command, cmd.exe auto closes. I want it to remain open so that i can enter other commands as when needed

Comment: Such as cd to a directory. then execute some commands. then cd to another directory. This requires me to have that cmd open for the above operations to be performed and not close each time a command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the /k argument, which tells CMD.exe to open, run the specified command, then keep the window open.